# Python Module Can Not be Found Even Though It Is Installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, terminal, module

I used python and pandas so many times in VS Code but It causes a problem right know : [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kx3D.jpg)
The terminal looks like this : [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9YE8.png) and I checked if matplotlib is installed or not but seems like it is installed [matplotlib check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abKUW.jpg). I don't know why this is happening but It was working until now.

Comment: I have the same problem in `logging module` and I search many pages but don't find any solution so I changed my IDE to Pycharm or Eclipse or Jupyter Notebook....So Change Your IDE visual code is good for basic python

Comment: Actually you're right, It is working on Juypter...I'll look for them. Thnak you @AnuragDabas

Comment: yeah if you are working with `matplotlib,seaborn,numpy` and `pandas`........ `jupyter notebook `is an ideal choice @apotamkinn

Comment: @AnuragDabas Actually I was using Jupyter on VS Code. But It does not work so we'll move on :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the python environment you are currently using in VS Code is different from the python environment used by the VS Code terminal.

**Solution**: Please close the currently used VS Code terminal (click the icon "Kill Terminal"), then select the python environment that has installed the required module at the bottom left of VS Code, and then use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open the new VS Code terminal.

In addition, I noticed that you are using a powershell terminal. If you are using a virtual environment or conda environment, we need to activate this environment in the terminal (Usually it will automatically activate when a new terminal is opened.):

[image]

Check module:

[image]

Run:

[image]

Reference: [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).